# CSS Spec: child element exceeds left edge in a Block Formatting Context

Tags: css

I am reading [CSS Spec 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). Regarding Block Formatting Context, I find this:

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). ..., unless the box
>   establishes a new block formatting context (...).

In this example, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t27ewcmx/1/), the parent element forms a new Block Formatting Context because of `float:left`. And its child element has `position:relative`, which doesn't form a new BFC. However, the child overlaps with the parent. This behavior seems conflict with the spec:

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block

Could anybody help to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `position: relative` to offset the child from its original, static position. From [section 9.4.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning) (emphasis mine):

> **Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow** or floated, it may be shifted relative to this position.

This means that layout happens *before* relative positioning, which means that as far as layout is concerned it is the static position, not the relative position that is bound by these rules.

Removing `position: relative; left: -50px`, you can see that [the child element's left outer edge does indeed touch the parent's left content edge](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/t27ewcmx/2) (and likewise for the right, but only because the child width is auto).

Comment: So I think the relative positioning happens **after** the BFC rules are applied.

Comment: Yes, each BFC performs its own normal flow layout. This is why, in CSS3, a BFC is also known as a flow root.